# Settings.bundle deployment with Cydia

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cydia, settings.bundle

I have created a settings.bundle and the settings are visible when I debug it on my iPhone. But when I upload it to a repository the users can not see the settings in the Settings.app.

So how do I make the settings appear in Settings.app on jailbroken devices? Is there something I can put in the preinst-script to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you made your .deb, did you put the necessary files in? Were they set with the right permissions? Can you have one of your users check and see if it's getting installed, but just not showing up? Did you setup your Prefs bundle as described on this page? http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PreferenceBundles